# About a conjecture of Fuhua Wei and Shanhe Wu

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I have this problem to solve wich has a link with the conjecture of this [link](http://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~matsefi/Octogon/volumes/volume1/article1_18.pdf)
 (at the end) this is the following :

> Let $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ be real positive numbers with $0\leq\alpha\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $n\geq2$ an integer then we have :
>   $$\sin^{2\alpha}\left[\frac{\arctan(\frac{x_1}{x_2})+\arctan(\frac{x_2}{x_3})+\cdots+\arctan(\frac{x_n}{x_1})}{n}\right]\leq\frac{1}{2^{\alpha}}$$

I know that we have :
$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=\arctan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})+k\pi$

So we have :
$$\sin(\frac{\arctan(\frac{x_1}{x_2})+\arctan(\frac{x_2}{x_3})+\cdots+\arctan(\frac{x_n}{x_1})}{n})=\sin(\frac{\arctan(\frac{\tau_1-\tau_3+\tau_5-\cdots}{1-\tau_2+\tau_4-\cdots})+k'\pi}{n})$$

Where $\tau_k$ is the $k^{th}$ [symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) in function of the $\frac{x_m}{x_{m+1}}$ and $k'$ an integer that we have to determine.

But after that I'm stuck . Any helps is appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha=1$ and $n=2$ your inequality becomes:
$$
\sin\left({\arctan(x_1/x_2)+\arctan(x_2/x_1)\over 2}\right)^2\le{1\over2}.
$$
But $\arctan(x_1/x_2)+\arctan(x_2/x_1)=\pi/2$,
and $\sin(\pi/4)^2\approx0.578>1/2$, so the above inequality is false.

EDIT

Just to note that after the changes, the inequality to prove turns out to be independent of $\alpha$ and is equivalent to:
$$
\frac{\arctan(\frac{x_1}{x_2})+\arctan(\frac{x_2}{x_3})+\cdots+\arctan(\frac{x_n}{x_1})}{n}\le{\pi\over4}.
$$
But that fails for $n=3$ with $x_1=1$, $x_2=3$, $x_3=2$, because:
$$
\frac{\arctan(1/3)+\arctan(3/2)+\cdots+\arctan(2)}{3}
\approx0.803898>{\pi\over4}
$$

Comment: Yes I was working sorry , I have forgotten a power for the $\sin(x)$ can I correct ?

Comment: Of course you can: click "edit" under your question.

Comment: If you have a counter-example to this I will accept your answer .Thanks for your interest !

Comment: Looks like my counterexample still works.

Comment: Ah...radian or degree ? Because for me $sin(\frac{\pi}{4})^2=0.5$

Comment: Wait a moment: you then mean $\sin^{2\alpha}[\dots]$ and not $\sin[\dots]^{2\alpha}$.

Comment: Yes it's ambiguous sorry this is $\sin^{2\alpha}[...]$.

Comment: And it's $0\leq \alpha\leq 0.5$ as in the document sorry sorry...

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution (+1) , Have you some ideas to conclude this ?

Comment: Yes: I just added another counterexample.

Comment: Yes accept your answer but now I think this is the opposite inequality wich works...Are you agree ?

Comment: Well, for $n=3$ with $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=3$ the original inequality works strictly.

Comment: So with the condition $x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots\leq x_n$ it's works ? Furthermore I find this theorem http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-jruiz8/beamer/TrigPresentation/trigpresentation_1.pdf

Comment: With that condition it seems to work, but I only made a limited number of tests.

Comment: I think you can use the Equal Variable method to finish this conjecture . See here https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf .Theorem 1.3 . Have a good day .